# Install Plugins on RabbitMQ hosted in Amazon MQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-mq

I have a RabbitMQ hosted in Amazon MQ, but im finding it difficult to find any documentation or guides to how to install this plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/. In the documentation it does not state how to remotely(Since Amazon MQ does not allow direct CLI access). I tried this command: `rabbitmqadmin --base-uri=@url --vhost=/ --ssl --username=@user --password=@pass rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange`

Answer (score 1):

rabbitmq-plugins  --node=rabbit@host -l enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange

the above command is right but amazonMQ doesn't have `rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange`installed so unless we can ssh into it and install it there is no way to use it with amazonmq